# recombinant gametes

Tags: homework, reproduction

> Suppose you are able to observe under a microscope the total number
>   of meiotic divisions occurring in one gonad of a given individual and to
>   outnumber exactly the crossovers between two given loci for which that
>   individual is dihybrid. If the frequency of these particular
>   crossovers is 100% (that is to say that every meiosis exhibits one
>   crossing over between the two loci you consider) you anticipate that
>   the total percentage of recombinant gametes would be equal to:

I don't understand how to solve this.

Comment: What have you thought of so far?